# System error at shutdown unmounting external USB drive

Tags: usb, shutdown, unmount

I use an external USB hard drive for my data store. I have the drive mounted at boot time via fstab. When I first set this up when doing a fresh install of 20.04 a few months ago, everything worked without complaint from the system.  However, a month or so ago I started getting an error when I shut down the system.

The error is:

```
 [FAILED] Failed unmounting /mnt/usb-Seagate_Expansion_NAAQ6PWP-0:0-part2.
```

Here is the line in fstab that mounts the drive:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Seagate_Expansion_NAAQ6PWP-0:0-part2 /mnt/usb-Seagate_Expansion_NAAQ6PWP-0:0-part2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Here is a screenshot of the Disks utility showing the drive:

[Screenshot of the disk displayed in the Disks utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBcQm.png)

The system pauses at the error screen momentarily and then shuts down.  Otherwise, everything seems to be normal.  I welcome any advice.

Cheers,

Dan K.